# Xcode 6.2 Parse Issue in iOS system classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I just upgraded to XCode 6.2 this morning and on loading my project received 17 errors. They are all identical:

```
Parse Issue
Expected '=' after '__NSi_8_2'
```

They are all in Apple's own classes:

```
NSProcessInfo.h
NSExtensionContext.h
UIFontDescriptor.h
UIFont.h
UIApplication.h
UILocalNotification.h
```

Anyone know what's going on here? I obviously can't build my project but if it's an XCode issue with iOS 8.2 who knows when it will be patched.

**EDIT:** Added some images to show details

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post some code ,its hard to say anything with provided information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that may come across this issue, I eventually found the solution. The Xcode project kept the iOS 8.1 frameworks rather than upgrading to the iOS 8.2 versions in Xcode 6.2. All I had to do was remove Foundation, CoreFoundation and UIKit frameworks then re-add them.